# Custom gtkrc for a specific application in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: themes, gnome, ubuntu-16.04, gtk2

I use Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS.
I installed the Arc-Darker theme from the repository given in the github page.
I installed GVim from Ubuntu software center.
I use solarized dark theme in GVim but there is a thin horizontal white line at the bottom.

[GVim window with white line at the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeshn.png)

I don't want this line in white (in the red reactangle). I want this line to be dark, like the background of the solarized theme.

I changed the background color in /usr/share/themes/Arc-Darker/gtk-2.0/gtkrc to the background color of solarized theme :

```
gtk-color-scheme = "bg_color: #002B36"
```

It solves the problem as you can see here :
[GVim without the white line at the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47XSb.png)

The problem is other gtk2 application use this background now. So, some part of these applications are dark. I don't want this. I want other application to keep the original theme color.

**Question :**

Is it possible to add an option somewhere in gtkrc file or an other file in the theme folder to permanently change "gtk-color-scheme" property of **GVim only** and **only for this theme** ?

PS : I am sorry, I am not allowed to put pictures directly here, and i can't put more than 2 links...